# Do the NIC/Driver/OS/CLR Present Any Limitation on the Number of Concurrent Requests/Connections a Server Application Can Have?

Tags: c#, .net, concurrency, server

Usually when developing Server Applications, you hear developers say
"I started with Multi-Threading, and could get to ~1,000 concurrent users,
and when I used Asynchronous Programming, the number grew to ~10,000".

We usually put the focus on the code.

But assume for a moment this **ideal** scenario:
You wrote a really well code, that can get to a really high number of concurrent users,
and you also have a really strong internet connection, with a high bandwidth, and really low latency.

So If you put these 2 parts aside (for the sake of this question), and assume they are ideal,
aren't there any limitations from the parts that are in between them?

"The parts that are between them" are for example:
- The NIC (HW)
- The Driver (SW)
- The OS (SW)
- .NET's CLR (SW - assume we're using .NET)

Doesn't one of these present some limitation?
For example a limitation on the number of open TCP Connections..

Important note:
The application is not a web-application running on a Web-server.
It is an .EXE, running on Windows (on the CLR, if to be accurate).

Comment: `Doesn't one of these present some limitation?` the answer is yes. If you want a broader discussion on how to maximize concurrent connections i think this is a little too broad for stack-overflow

Comment: Thank you TheGeneral. Not a broader discussion, but just to understand the limits. For example, what is Windows' or the CLR's limit? Do they present a limit on the number of concurrent TCP connections?

Comment: Basically the numbers you have quoted sound directly related to the thread pool, async await, return threads that are awaited for IO bound operations back to the OS and allow them to be reused. I am no expert here, however i think there are many things that could reduce the amount of connections you can serve concurrently, mostly configurations with IIS and what server operating system you are using and how you have written you applications, as mentioned above.